# How to save a list as a new template which is already saved as template

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can i save a list as an new template which is already saved as template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list Template (.stp) is a reusable , so you can use it multiple times by providing a new name on each time.

If you are looking to export with content, then you can navigate to list settings -> save a list as template -> provide a new name and save it to list gallery

Have you been facing any trouble while saving a template which already saved as template

Comment: Oh your right. How dumb of me. Thanks for the help